# Magento 2 - Values required set to no , still get You must choose options for your item

Tags: magento2, addtocart, color-swatches

I set to No the Values required and Visible for the size and color from Product Attributes and when I try to add an item to cart , I get this error : You must choose options for your item.

What should i do? Sorry , but it's my first project with Magento.
I will have a bookshop and I don't need color and size to be there , just the quantity .

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution will be to create another attribute set for your products without the color and size attributes as far as you do not need them. Or just remove them from your current attribute set.